# Extract ID From A YouTube Video iFrame Link With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I've got this youtube video link:

```
iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XbGs_qK2PQA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` (Hell Yeah! Eminem :P)
```

I want to retrieve only `"XbGs_qK2PQA"` from this whole bunch. Got the `src` with

```
$('iframe').attr('src');
```

How do I remove that else characters?

NB: I've got a trick. Reverse the string and then append the characters into a variable until I find a `'/'`, but how do I achieve this via **jquery/javascript**?

Answer (score 3):

If you just have one `iframe` in page

```
$('iframe').attr('src').split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
var src = $('iframe').attr('src').match(/[^/]*$/)[0];
```

The regex will match the rest of the string after the last `/` character.